# this is an issue concerning styling html elements

Tags: php, html, css

bellow is my code that is suppose to create a search box and then style it. For some reason the css properties that I try to give to the box does not apply. I tried having the css in a separate file and also in the script as shown bellow. What is the problem (I'm using netbeans and the file is a .php)

here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>cats</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search me..." required>
            <input type="button" value="Search">
        </form>

        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
form {
                width:500px;
                margin:50px auto;
}
.Search {
                padding:8px 15px;
                background:rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
                border:0px solid #dbdbdb;
}
.button {
                position:relative;
                padding:6px 15px;
                left:-8px;
                border:2px solid #207cca;
                background-color:#207cca;
                color:#fafafa;
}
.button:hover  {
                background-color:#fafafa;
                color:#207cca;



        </style>

        <?php

        // put your code here
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML elements don't actually have the css classes "attached" to them. How will it know what element to affect?

Comment: I see because I followed an example on the net and it was scripted like this

Comment: This might be helpful: [CSS Class Selectors @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)

Comment: Please edit your question title to "specify" what your problem is. Almost everyone who posts questions on Stack Overflow has an issue of some sort.

Comment: You need to find a better place to learn from then if this is the example they use.

Comment: use the id selector or class selector to style your css elements as in <form id="formStyle">your code</form>  and i would expect something like this in css : #formStyle { //style properties}

Comment: @showdev MarloC meant the vague title.

Answer (score 1):

You are using [CSS class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors). Give the elements you want to style the appropriate class attributes (as alluded to by patricksweeney):

```css
form {
    width:500px;
    margin:50px auto;
}
.search {
    padding:8px 15px;
    background:rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
    border:0px solid #dbdbdb;
}
.button {
    position:relative;
    padding:6px 15px;
    left:-8px;
    border:2px solid #207cca;
    background-color:#207cca;
    color:#fafafa;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color:#fafafa;
    color:#207cca;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search me..." required>
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: you beat me to it, and cleaned up the quirky capitalization as well, so I'll delete my answer. :-)